# Read temprature on estimote ibeacon

Tags: objective-c, swift, estimote

In obj-c I can get the temprature from a beacon with this block :

```
- (void)readTemperatureWithCompletion:(ESTNumberCompletionBlock)completion
```

How can I do this with SWIFT with a closure. I have been studying closures but still not sure how to run this block in SWIFT.

Can anyone advise ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
func beaconConnectionDidSucceeded(beacon: ESTBeacon) {
    NSLog("beaconConnectionDidSucceeded")
    beacon.readTemperatureWithCompletion() { value, error in
        NSLog("readTemperatureWithCompletion, value = \(value), error = \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, thanks! I updated the code above to use the trailing syntax and type inference as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is more correct

```
beacon.readTemperatureWithCompletion({(temp:NSNumber!, error:NSError?) -> () in
        if error? == nil{
            println("\(temp)")
        }else
        {
            println("Error \(error!.description)")
        }   
    })
```